# Probablility of string containing letters in order

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have an alphabet containing $m+1$ symbols, $\{a, b, c, d, e,..., \$\}$, where $p = \Pr(a) = \Pr(b) =\cdots$, and $\Pr(\$) = 1 - (\Pr(a)+\Pr(b)+\cdots)=1-mp$.

For a random string of length $n$, what is the probability that the letters ${a, b, c, ...}$ (not including $\$$), occur in order (not necessarily consecutively)?  In other words, the string is of length n and satisfies the regular expression $*a*b*c*\cdots$.

Some clarifications:

I just need the letters to appear in order sometime.  So acbc is ok because it contains $abc$ in that order.

I do need all m letters to appear in order.

Letters can be repeated.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the regular expression "abc...e" (without quotes) matches only those strings beginning "abc", followed by three of any character, followed in turn by a single "e".  Let me ask some clarifying questions: Do you want all $m$ letters to occur in order?  Must the *first* occurrences of each letter be in order?  (That is, is "acbc" an acceptable prefix because "a", "b", and "c" do occur in order?  Or is it unacceptable because the first "c" precedes the first "b"?)  Or do you want *no* repeated letters (other than OTHER)?

Comment: sorry, I put in the "*" character, but it treated it as italics.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: OK, although that's still not the usual regular expression syntax (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), where "*" stands for Kleene star, not arbitrary wild card.  Still, I know what you mean.  You didn't answer the other question, though.  Do you need all letters to appear in order, or just a through e?

Comment: I edited the question a bit to make it more readable. I assumed *all* letters should be in order: that way it was written, as $a,b,c,\ldots,e,\ldots$, was a bit confusing since the $d$ was somehow missing. Correct back if I was wrong about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start answering a slightly different question. Given a random sequence of  symbols, $x_1,x_2,\ldots\in\{a,b,\ldots,z,\$\}$, where I let $z$ denote the $m$th and last letter in the alphabet, let $q_k$ denote the likelihood that $k$ is the first location for which $x_1\ldots x_k\sim*a*b*\cdots*z$.

Obviously, the likelihood $P_n$ that a random string of length $n$ contains the letters $a,b,\ldots,z$ in order, i.e. matches $*a*b*\cdots*z*$, is $P_n=\sum_{k\le n} q_k$.

We can describe $x_1\ldots x_k\sim *a*b*\cdots*z$ uniquely by selecting the first possible location of $a$, of $b$, etc. That corresponds to a string $[\hat{}a]^*a[\hat{}b]^*b\ldots[\hat{}z]^*z$ where $[\hat{}a]^*$ means an arbitrary number of characters that are not $a$, etc.

This gives us a set of $m-1$ locations amongst the first $k-1$ positions of the string for the first occurrence of the $m-1$ letters, which can be selected in ${k-1\choose m-1}$ different ways, plus position $k$ position for $z$. Each of these $m$ occurrences has probability $p$ of being $a, b, \ldots, z$ respectively. the remaining $k-m$ positions can be anything except the upcoming letter and so each have probability $1-p$. This makes
$$
q_k={k-1\choose m-1} p^m (1-p)^{k-m}.
$$

The probability $P_n=\sum_{k=m}^n q_n$ that the letters may be found in order in a string of length $n$ is then
$$
P_n=\sum_{k=m}^n {k-1\choose m-1} p^m (1-p)^{k-m}.
$$
Trying to simplify this (using Maple) gives an expression in terms of hypergeometric series, which doesn't add anything since the hypergeometric series is defined as such a sum.

Comment: There are a couple small mistakes. First, in the expression for $q_k$, the exponent of $1-p$ should be $k-m$, rather than $n-m$. This changes the sum for $P_n$, which would now have a closed-form solution since $\sum_p \binom pb y^p=\frac{y^b}{(1-y)^{b+1}}$. Actually, the current expression for your $P_n$ has a closed-form expression, using the hockey stick identity (no hypergeometric series needed).

Comment: @RusMay: Thanks! Should be fixed now. I had originally used $n$ instead of $k$ until I realised that was a bad idea, and failed to correct it consistently.